# How do I get the length of a structure? (NASM)

Tags: assembly, struct, nasm

If I define a structure like so:

```
section .bss
    struc mystruc
        .x: resb 1
        .y: resb 1
    endstruc
```

How would I get the length of the structure?

Comment: NASM always defines a label `mystruc_size`

Comment: @ecm What is the point of omitting a single `t` in `struc`. Is it for some historical reason?

Comment: @xiver77 Yes, I suppose. This is the standard macro name chosen by NASM. If you prefer you can `%idefine struct struc`, or even re-create the set of macros [like I did for a feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/nasm/feature-requests/160/) a while ago.